# Xdebug terminates early with no errors but site runs fine when its disabled

Tags: php, drupal-7, xdebug

I am using Xdebug from within the PhpStorm IDE. I use Xdebug all the time without issue. I now ran into a weird issue - I have a line of code in for which Xdebug terminates immediately, I get a white screen of death, and I have no Apache, PHP logs etc. when I turn off the breakpoint (or Xdebug itself) that page runs fine and actually runs the code as expected. This is very confusing to me and I'm wondering what types of issues this might be stemming from.

I don't think the actual line of code is helpful, but here it is:

```
$options[$bundle][$entity_id] = check_plain($this->getLabel($entity));
```

https://cgit.drupalcode.org/entityreference/tree/plugins/selection/EntityReference_SelectionHandler_Generic.class.php#n173

This line of code is in the Drupal 7 Entityreference module.

EDIT:
Again, don't know if this might be a factor, but I'm running this site on a vagrant box.

Comment: have you stepped into the method, it could be an exception further down in the stack (in the Drupal code) ?

Comment: Yes, I have stepped into the method. When I step in, walk through each step until the end, it completes the function call just fine. Only when I step over it does its have that issue. And, its has the issue the first time its called, so its not like its only failing on a different itteration....